# Disable foreign key check in insert operation in MySql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table which is using to map **two primary keys of other two tables.** i make these two fields as foreign keys. The mapping table has **no primary key**  When i am trying to insert 2 value which already in that two tables, i am getting *Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails* error.
How can i solve this issue ?

My Table is like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fuse_package_component_members    
( component_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
     member_type int(11) NOT NULL, 
     member_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
     active_date date NOT NULL, 
     inactive_date date NOT NULL, 
     KEY component_id (component_id), 
     KEY member_id (member_id) ) 
   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

ALTER TABLE fuse_package_component_members 
ADD CONSTRAINT comp_id_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (component_id) REFERENCES fuse_component_definition (component_id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
ADD CONSTRAINT ele_id_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES fuse_product_element (element_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: will need more information than that. There would have been a typo or other kind of mistake. show your table schema query and same data if possible

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fuse_package_component_members` (
  `component_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active_date` date NOT NULL,
  `inactive_date` date NOT NULL,
  KEY `component_id` (`component_id`),
  KEY `member_id` (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

this is my table

Comment: ALTER TABLE `fuse_package_component_members`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `comp_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`) REFERENCES `fuse_component_definition` (`component_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ele_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `fuse_product_element` (`element_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

This is the Constraints for table.

Answer (score 5):

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
UPDATE ...
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the foreign key constraint from the table, insert the data and re-enforce the constraint..

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP FOREIGN KEY constraint_name
```

if you want to check the constraint name, just run the query

```
show create table table_name
```

It will show you the whole schema along with all the imposed constraints...

Add the constraints again

A good link to follow -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: I have to keep that foreign key Constraints for future use, same time i have to do the insert operation :(

Comment: The record entry that you are adding doesn't exist in the parent row. I thought you just want to move the data and will add up the constraint again..

Comment: Both ids are there in parent tables

Comment: (component_id) REFERENCES fuse_component_definition (component_id)  (member_id) REFERENCES fuse_product_element (element_id)

The new value that you are inserting is already in both the tables ...right?

Comment: I just removed the foreign key constraints